# PHP exif_read_data not return orientation

Tags: php

I am using `exif_read_data`, but it is not returning images orientation. Below is my code:

```
$path = base_url()."assets/procedure_logo/".$procedure_logo;
print_r($path);
$exif = exif_read_data($path,"FILE,COMPUTED,ANY_TAG,IFD0,THUMBNAIL,COMMENT,EXIF", true);
print_r($exif); die();
```

Print path in I get fullpath like

http://www.ilockitout.net/assets/procedure_logo/12848C457-0482-495A-8756-038C9B7980501344008487.JPG

When I print `$exif` I got array like this:

```
Array
(
[FILE] => Array
    (
        [FileName] => 12848C457-0482-495A-8756-038C9B7980501344008487.JPG
        [FileDateTime] => 0
        [FileSize] => 25770
        [FileType] => 2
        [MimeType] => image/jpeg
        [SectionsFound] => COMMENT
    )

[COMPUTED] => Array
    (
        [html] => width="640" height="480"
        [Height] => 480
        [Width] => 640
        [IsColor] => 1
    )

[COMMENT] => Array
    (
        [0] => CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 50

    )

 )
```

Comment: I'm confused what your question is.

Comment: Are you sure the information is in the photo? [This](http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ilockitout.net%2Fassets%2Fprocedure_logo%2F12848C457-0482-495A-8756-038C9B7980501344008487.JPG) suggests it isn't.

Comment: yes i want orientation for ratation image because when i upload images is 90 degree so i want some images orientation set

Comment: Your image was NOT produced by a digital camera, thus it will have NO rotation data stored in it!!!
----
Check this [github page](https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples), these sample images have this metadata, so you can test your code on them.